# Devastating hangups when trying to improve documentation

Tags: bug, documentation

I've tried to improve an item in the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag area, namely https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/507/files-and-i-o-streams#t=201607280403587709618 and every time I try to do so in Firefox (47.0.1) or Chrome (52.0.2743.82) on my Mac OS X 10.11.6 machine, it gets to be an exercise in frustration as the Javascript hangs for about 40 seconds, until Firefox gives me a chance to kill the script — Chrome gives up the ghost and doesn't continue to display the page.  It took me 6 hangups of 40s each, during which I can do nothing with my browser because SO is hung, to get the article somewhat edited.  I'm not willing to spend longer checking whether what I did is perfect (so it isn't perfect; it's just better than what was there before).  But when you can't even scroll through the text without incurring a delay, you don't futz around making everything perfect.

This is not a good way to say that an item is too long.  The editor should not hang up.  It shouldn't need to go fetching stuff once I'm typing — it seems to be trying to access material in the background, though I'm not sure what (especially since the answer never arrives).  This is related to other problems I've seen.  It is a crucial problem to resolve.

Other issues with Documentation:

- Ability to upvote/downvote comments.
- No visible tracking of which reviews you've visited.
- The navigation back to somewhere useful (e.g. dashboard) after you've submitted something is klunky at best.

Comment: Can't repro on Firefox ESR 45.2, is a specific element of the page that triggers the issue or just about anything? BTW, are you using the "expand examples to the side" option?

Comment: We're aware of performance issue with loading drafts on topics with either a lot of examples or a lot of changes. Looking into that... (And there's a better dupe target somewhere, but I don't have it readily available on my machine here at home). Making browsers not crash is most definitely a priority, and I'm hoping to have a better answer some time tomorrow or Friday.

Comment: @Braiam: it seems to be somewhat inconsistent as to when it shows up.  I've had people on Windows 10 say it's not a problem for them.  I don't know whether it is just when you go through the 'Improve' menu item from the dashboard.  Now it is submitted, I can scroll up and down OK.  It is an artifact of editing — that I'm sure.  I'm on a modest internet connection, but it is not so bad that it should be taking 40 seconds to download stuff; I downloaded an update to Chrome in a matter of a minute or less, and editing an SO Documentation item shouldn't be remotely comparable to that!

Comment: @AdamLear: there are definitely a lot of examples in the topic I was working with.  I'm not sure whether it is the size of the individual example or the number of topics or both or some other factor too (or instead), but I'm glad to hear you're aware of it, and that it is under attack.  Have you managed to get a repro?  Does this help you create one?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have a repro (but last time I tried to get through with it locally Visual Studio got in the way). As far as I know at the moment, we run a diff on every example to try and compare it with the previous version when a draft is in progress and that's ... bad. There may be other things  slowing down the works as well. Either way, I'm sure we can do better - it's on my list to attack first thing tomorrow.